# Prove that k successive calls to TREE-SUCCESSOR take O(k + h) time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-tree, traversal

This question has been around for while, but I still have a question please. I will discuss the following solution.

**Question**: Prove that no matter what node we start at in a height-`h` binary search tree, `k` successive calls to TREE-SUCCESSOR take `O(k + h)` time.

Given tree successor algorithm below, that given an x, it will find it's left-most node of right-subtree of `x`:

[image]

**Assumptions**: Assuming that the worst-case running time of `TREE-SUCCESSOR()` is O(h), where h is the height of binary search tree and the tree will not be changed between successive calls of the method. The worst case happens when next successor is a leaf at depth h.

You need to call once the method to get the next successor and you need `O(h)` time for that. Once when you have the next successor you simply can store it and for every other call, you can return it in `O(1)`. Since, you have `k−1` remaining calls, the running time is `O(k)`. Combining with the above, you have that the total running time is `O(h)+O(k)=O(k+h)`.

**Question**: I am not sure by the last statement about how we got running time O(k) please? I assume k successive calls to `TREE-SUCCESSOR()` means that we are calling it k times on probably same or different nodes? If that is the case, we know that worst time for `TREE-SUCCESSOR`  is `O(h)`, so how we got a total time of `O(h+k)` please? I can see that if we call `TREE-SUCCESSOR()` `k` times, then we should get worst-case of `O(kh)`.

**Edit**: I would assume probably that `k` succissive calls to `TREE-SUCCESSOR()` means: `TREE-SUCCESSOR()+⋯+TREE-SUCCESSOR(): k times`?

Comment: By "k successive calls to TREE-SUCCESSOR", they mean do `x = TREE-SUCCESOR(x)` k times.  The result of each call is the argument for the next, so you are traversing the tree in order.

Comment: @MattTimmermans.Thank you. Does that mean on the same node `x` or for different nodes `x` please?

Comment: @MattTimmermans. Thank you very much. So are you saying it's literally `TREE-SUCCESOR(TREE-SUCCESOR(TREE-SUCCESOR(TREE-SUCCESOR(x)...)))` please? We should start from the root node I guess `r`?

Comment: Yes, but you can start at any node.

Comment: @MattTimmermans. Since it's worst case, so we should start from the root `r` please? It's not given, but I assume from time analysis, they started from root node?

Comment: Why do you think the root node is the worst case?

Comment: @MattTimmermans. You are right, that is false assumption.

Comment: @MattTimmermans. Can you please discuss what this at least mean, "Since, you have `k−1 ` remaining calls, the running time is `O(k)`"?

Comment: @MattTimmermans. For the first successor, it's abvious we need `O(h)=height`, but why for others calls to successor (`k-1`)we need `O(1)`? If we need `O(h)` for the first, then why we only need `O(K) `for the others (`k-1` other calls) making up a total time of `O(K+H)` please?

Comment: As @StefanPochmann indicates, that whole paragraph is based on the assumption that the argument is the same in every call, which is incorrect.  That paragraph is entirely invalid, so it doesn't matter what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's commonly known that an in-order traversal of a binary tree takes O(n) time using this method.  Your problem is to prove the equivalent statement for *partial* traversals of a binary tree.

A weaker version of the statement you have to prove is that the *amortized* cost of each successive call is O(1).  I would prove *that* statement using the [potential method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_method).  A similar method can be used for the proof you need:

To show that k successive calls require O(k+h) time, we find a "bank function" **B** that operates on the current node, and show that:

1. The time required for **y = TREE-SUCCESSOR(x)** is in **O(1 + B(y) - B(x))**; and
2. **0 <= B(x) <= h** for all x

It follows from (1) that after **k** successive calls such that **y = TREE-SUCCESSOR<sup>k</sup>(x)**, the total time is in **O(k + B(y)-B(x))**, and it follows from(2) that **B(y)-B(x)** is in **O(h)**, so this proves that the time is in **O(k + h)**

A bank function that works is **B(x) = (h + d<sub>L</sub>(x) - d<sub>R</sub>(x))/2**, where **d<sub>L</sub>** is the number of left-child links on the path from root to x, and **d<sub>R</sub>** is the number of right-child links on the path from the root to x.

Consider the cases of non-bounded work in **TREE-SUCCESOR(x)**:

1. When x has a right child, the extra work is proportional to the number of left-child links added in **TREE-MINIMUM**.  That is the change in **d<sub>L</sub>**.  The number of right-child links increases by only 1, so the extra work is proportional to the change in **B**.
2. When x has no right child, the extra work is proportional to the number of right-child links we remove by traversing to the parent.  That is the decrease in **d<sub>R</sub>**.  The number of left-child links changes by only 1, so again the extra work is proportional to the change in **B**.

Those are the only two cases, and in both cases we have total work in **O(1 + B(y) - B(x))**.  Condition 1 is true.  Condition 2 is also trivially true from the definition of **B**, so the statement is proven.

Comment: Thank you very much. How you came up with bank function `B(x) = (h + dL - dR)/2` please?

Comment: I started with the two cases of unbounded work, and invented a function that changed proportionally and stayed within [0,h]

Comment: Amazing solution. Thanks. So `d_l` lowest value is 0 and same for `d_r`. Similarily, the highest value is `d_l=h`, this making bank function`h+h/2 = h`.